# Trying to make a Go Launcher theme, AndroidManifest is bugging

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to make my own Go Launcher icon pack. This is what it looks like so far;[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOL9x.png)

Im getting an error;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

My manifest looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application>
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/theme_title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity>
        android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/theme_title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Action" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.THEME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- SUPPORTED LAUNCHERS -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.adw.launcher.THEMES" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Apex -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.THEME" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- GO LAUNCHER -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.THEME_SCENE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

I dont know what the error is, cant find it in the log. Anyways,
Here is the log; keep in mind this is my first "app"

```
2016-01-29 17:14:03,286 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,358 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-141.2456560, 01 Dec 2015 00:00) 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,358 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,358 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_72-b15 (Oracle Corporation) 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,358 [     72]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.72-b15 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,360 [     74]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.5 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Djb.vmOptions=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\boot.jar -Didea.jre.check=false 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,434 [    148]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 73 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,436 [    150]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2016-01-29 17:14:03,437 [    151]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2016-01-29 17:14:05,120 [   1834]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 30 plugins initialized in 784 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:05,128 [   1842]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.1.5.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage, EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google Analytics Uploader (1.0), Google App Indexing (0.1), Google Cloud Testing (1.0), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), Maven Integration, Properties Support, SDK Updater (1.0), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), hg4idea (10.0) 
2016-01-29 17:14:05,785 [   2499]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=1276510208 
2016-01-29 17:14:05,850 [   2564]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2016-01-29 17:14:05,863 [   2577]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2016-01-29 17:14:06,403 [   3117]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2016-01-29 17:14:06,759 [   3473]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2016-01-29 17:14:07,391 [   4105]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2016-01-29 17:14:07,477 [   4191]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 22 project components initialized in 467 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:07,478 [   4192]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:09,111 [   5825]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Received external Windows command line: current directory C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio, command line "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe"  
2016-01-29 17:14:09,213 [   5927]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 88 application components initialized in 4058 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:09,281 [   5995]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 6628 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:10,088 [   6802]   INFO - ellij.ide.CommandLineProcessor - ----- 
2016-01-29 17:14:10,834 [   7548]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2016-01-29 17:14:11,583 [   8297]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 146 project components initialized in 1381 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:11,723 [   8437]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 140 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:13,432 [  10146]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - M:\MFlat\Mflat\.idea\misc.xml case-sensitivity: false 
2016-01-29 17:14:14,961 [  11675]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 4834 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,209 [  11923]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 2942 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,389 [  12103]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,393 [  12107]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,403 [  12117]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,407 [  12121]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,833 [  12547]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8' 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,834 [  12548]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Found embedded Gradle 2.8 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,848 [  12562]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'ApexIconPackSample'. 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,971 [  12685]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71 
2016-01-29 17:14:15,979 [  12693]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71 
2016-01-29 17:14:16,032 [  12746]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2016-01-29 17:14:16,139 [  12853]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2016-01-29 17:14:16,354 [  13068]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 8 
2016-01-29 17:14:16,924 [  13638]   INFO - nject.config.XPathSupportProxy - XPath Support is not available 
2016-01-29 17:14:17,032 [  13746]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\BremFM\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo7.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\BremFM\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit2.gradle] 
2016-01-29 17:14:17,327 [  14041]   INFO - attrs.AttributeDefinitionsImpl - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2016-01-29 17:14:18,185 [  14899]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
2016-01-29 17:14:19,742 [  16456]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,232 [  24946]   INFO - oid.AndroidSdkModuleCustomizer - Setting SDK in the module model: Android API 15 Platform @ C:\Users\BremFM\AppData\Local\Android\sdk 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,470 [  25184]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle successful for project 'ApexIconPackSample'. 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,509 [  25223]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources] 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,522 [  25236]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,536 [  25250]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,539 [  25253]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8' 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,539 [  25253]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Found embedded Gradle 2.8 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,539 [  25253]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\BremFM\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo8.gradle] 
2016-01-29 17:14:28,540 [  25254]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\BremFM\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo8.gradle] 
2016-01-29 17:14:29,250 [  25964]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 74 ms 
2016-01-29 17:14:29,285 [  25999]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:29,288 [  26002]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:29,300 [  26014]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:29,301 [  26015]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-01-29 17:14:30,826 [  27540]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 75 ms
```

regards,
me

Comment: just realized I screwed up the log. How do I fix that? It was all inside the code BB codes.

Comment: you know you can edit your question? the "edit button" is below the android tag

Comment: I know, but dont know how to make the code appear in the spoiler

Comment: when in edit mode click on "formatting help" and scroll down until you find the explanation for "spoiler"

Comment: goddangit, nothing seems to work lol I know Im dumb

Comment: For the record, the `go` tag is for Google's Go programming language and not the Go launcher on android.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - thanks, I *was* wondering about that

Comment: What is your specific question? What problem are you having? Please don't post pictures of code, post code.

Comment: whoops, its not only code, it is a screenshot including the short log, directories and android manifest.

Comment: @BramvanHaaren It's all text. Pictures of text won't let us copy and paste to recreate your problem (we still don't know exactly what problem we're looking for) or Ctrl+F or any other text based ways to help you. Pictures of text don't help.

Comment: Corey, is it better now?